# ADF- data flow on fail but pipleline fails

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have implemented in my data flow that if it fails, do an action using on flow which basically moves the bad file to a folder. That is working perfectly as expected on fail.

My question is--- the pipeline as a whole is reported as failed in the scenario. Is that by default behavior like that or there is a setting that I can set to report Pipeline as Success if the error is handled on fail.

Here is a screenshot. 1st one shows that on fail action is taken care of from the data flow.
Second one shows that still the pipeline shows a fail. If on fail scanario is handled, I want the pipeline to show as success.

[image]

[image: Pipeline fail]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is same as this [Do If Else block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-pipeline-failure-error-handling#do-if-else-block). This will lead pipeline to a failure as per the documentation.

To succeed the pipeline, you need to add a dummy activity on the skip of the succeeded activity. This will ensure the pipeline success when the failed activity executes (Success activity will be skipped). Follow the steps provided in this [Do If Skip Else block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-pipeline-failure-error-handling#do-if-skip-else-block).

You can see the pipeline got succeeded when we use **`Do If Skip Else block`** approach.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, I figured out the same solution. Gracias